# Apache - Browsing of any domain URL is pointing to same folder

Tags: php, linux, apache, .htaccess

We have hosted multiple PHP websites in different domains in same server. Each domain have it own folder under **/var/www/html**. For e.g.

```
example1.com is pointing to /var/www/html/example1.com
example2.com is pointing to /var/www/html/example2.com
example3.com is pointing to /var/www/html/example3.com
```

etc..

Since Saturday, when I browse example1.com or `example2.com` or `example3.com`, it is showing same content in browser. That means every time I browse it is showing website content from **/var/www/html/example3.com** folder. I'm not sure how this change happened. May be one of our ex-employees changed this.

So I checked httpd.conf file in `/etc/httpd/conf`. Here documentroot is set correctly for all the domains. As I'm new to web administration, I'm not sure where exactly I've to correct to make all websites point to right folder.

1. What exactly is this problem? How will I rectify this?
2. Do I need to correct this in http.conf file or .htaccess file in every domain folders?

I'm struggling since yesterday. Any help is really appreciated.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: can you post what you see in /etc/httpd/conf also see if there is a configuration in /etc/apache2/sites-available

Comment: also check the vhosts conf file in extra too, this where virtualhosts should be defined if you don't sites-available/enabled feature

Comment: I'm using Amazon Linux Server. I didn't see /etc/apache2/sites folder. In httpd/conf folder, I can see httpd.conf and couple of ssl related files.

Comment: @Capsule. Hey, I'm not sure what you mean here. Can you please let me know the path for vhosts con file?

Comment: Paste the content of the virtual hosts section

Answer (score 0):

Finally I'm able to resolve the issue. I have about four websites with different domains running in this server. For couple of websites, under VirtualHost tag, DocumentRoot and ServerName were missing. After I added those values and restarted the apache server, it started working.

The incorrect entry was looking like this:

`<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin demo@demo.com
ServerAlias www.example1.com
</VirtualHost>`

I changed that as mentioned below:

`<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin demo@demo.com
ServerName example1.com
ServerAlias www.example1.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example1.com/
</VirtualHost>`

Thank you all for the help.